# Spring XML configuration, default-lazy-init and spring properties not working

Tags: spring, properties, lazy-initialization

I would like to determine if my beans are lazy init or not depending on a property loaded from a properties file.

My configuration file has a lot of properties in it that are parsed properly except for the one in default-lazy-init.

I've tried to set the lazy-init directly on a bean and i'm still having an exception.

Is the another way to do it?

**config.properties :**

```
lazyInit=true    
...
```

**springConfiguration-datasource.xml :**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

  <bean name="tDatasource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource" init-method="init" destroy-method="close" lazy-init="${lazyInit}">
...
```

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at com.icod.solapCore.test.SpringSupport.prepareTest(SpringSupport.java:19)
    at com.icod.solapCore.test.SolapCoreJunit4TestRunner.createTest(SolapCoreJunit4TestRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:248)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at com.icod.solapCore.test.SolapCoreJunit4TestRunner.run(SolapCoreJunit4TestRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 20 in XML document from class path resource [springConfiguration-datasource.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 144; cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${lazyInit}' is not a valid value for 'NMTOKEN'.
```

Comment: Please post your context to include de bean definition and the property placeholder configurer.

Comment: No, edit your question and add that and the bean definition and full exception log.

Comment: You can click the edit button on your question. Add the details there and remove these comments.

Comment: I am having the same issue, anyone resolved it yet?

Comment: If you are using maven, then you can use maven-replacer plugin

Answer (score 0):

As the context of this question is not clear. 
Still, I would like to recommend using **@Lazy annotation**, instead of configuring in spring bean configuration file.

This would certainly avoid all errors.